# Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I can't seem to resolve this issue with Spring Boot.  I have a very simple junit 5 test class that is annotated with @DataJpaTest.  It seems that no matter what I try I can't get any of my Junit tests to work in Spring Boot, running them in Idea Intellij IDE.

This my simple test class.

```
package com.nestrasoft.nestra;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@DataJpaTest
public class MainTestLoadContext {

    @Test
    void loadContextTest() {

    }
}
```

Log with error:

```
20:22:01.009 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
20:22:01.015 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
20:22:01.044 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.nestrasoft.nestra.MainTestLoadContext] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper]
20:22:01.053 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.nestrasoft.nestra.MainTestLoadContext], using SpringBootContextLoader
20:22:01.055 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.nestrasoft.nestra.MainTestLoadContext]: class path resource [com/nestrasoft/nestra/MainTestLoadContext-context.xml] does not exist
20:22:01.055 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.nestrasoft.nestra.MainTestLoadContext]: class path resource [com/nestrasoft/nestra/MainTestLoadContextContext.groovy] does not exist
20:22:01.055 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.nestrasoft.nestra.MainTestLoadContext]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
20:22:01.056 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.nestrasoft.nestra.MainTestLoadContext]: MainTestLoadContext does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
20:22:01.103 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.nestrasoft.nestra.MainTestLoadContext]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

    at spring.core@5.3.20/org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:236)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:392)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:262)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:89)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getTestContextManager(SpringExtension.java:294)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:205)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Test ignored.

Process finished with exit code 255
enter code here
enter code here
```

This is my Project Stucture
[intellij project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODqv1.png)

What Im expecting is that Spring Boot would pickup my @SpringBootApplication annotation in my Main Class.  Then it should traverse down from there picking up all the other configs and beans.  But it does not seem to search outside the test directory.

Does any one know how I can resolve this?

Comment: If you haven't customized the usage of Spring Boot heavily, try adding `@SpringBootTest` to your test class.

Comment: I had had tried that before and tried it again now with the same results as shown the log above.  Still not able to find the @SpringBootConfiguration which is in my Main class in the root directory and should be found.  I haven't customized the usage of Spring Boot -- its a very basic setup.

Comment: I just noticed the Java module line in the stack trace, as well as the `module-info.java` in your screenshot, my apologies. If you must use Java modules, try declaring the application class `open`. If you __could__ choose not to use Java modules then that would be much easier, though not safe in the long run.

Comment: Yes the use of Java modules is intentional -- I'm trying to implement it in my development.  Not sure I know what you mean declare application class open?  Could you clarify?

Comment: Interesting situation. Sorry I don't really have the environment handy for a `DataJpaTest` so I just tried with an empty Spring Boot application. I was able to reproduce the problem. The short answer is that the most reliable fix is to add a @ContextConfiguration to the test to explicitly point to the application config class. It's verbose, but should be able to overcome potential classloading issues. Also you only need to `export` the package (not the class), I was wrong saying `open`-ing.

Comment: I tried with @ContextConfiguration pointing to my application config class and it does work in finding it but still does not load this time because it is not creating my database.  I have a data.sql that is inserting records into tables and it fails on table does not exist. Very challenging to try to get the testcontext loaded.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: When I removed the info-module.java making this a non-module project it picked up the configuration class.  Seems that there are some inconsistencies in the way Spring Boot works with java modules.